# Drawing the intersection between glut objects in C

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glut

I am trying to draw the intersection between two glut objects, I managed to draw each object separately but I was wondering if I can draw only the intersection between the two objects?
My Code below draws a solid cube and sphere:

```
/* draw a cube */
        glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, 30.0 );
        glutSolidSphere(30,12,6);

        /* draw a wire sphere */
        glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, 30.0 );
        glutSolidCube(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenGL is not a scene graph (i.e. it doesn't maintain some kind of scene representation) but only draws simple primitives (points, line, triangles), one at a time, this is not immediately possible. There are methods to do this in image space, using multipass stencil buffer trickery. Here's a nice explanation: ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node22.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I couldn't find the class in the link you sent. I just need to draw the intersection between these simple objects. Could you please help me in that?

Comment: @SMH: What class? The link I gave you describes how to do GSC using the stencil buffer, in an algorithmic description, which you should implement. Other than that there is no way to use OpenGL for what you want to do. If you want to do CSG on the geometry level you'll have to work with the raw meshes (put them into a BSP or similar structure and to the CSG on that, Google "CSG using BSP".